# Is it possible to create a Windows Powershell Cmdlet/Module (or Portable Module) in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

Pretty much title, I'm trying to create a Powershell cmdlet that will run on Windows Powershell 5.1 (the Windows built in one, higher version if needed) from a C# .NET Core 3.1 project. I feel like this *should* be possible, but I can't find anything that will make it happen. Most of the documentation I find for writing cmdlets is for .NET Standard. I'm trying to use Core because it's new, but also because I wrote a few other projects with it and I'm looking to keep a consistent api. I'd also like to be able to project reference a few classes I've made in other .NET Core projects.

By Portable Module, I mean portable as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/writing-portable-modules?view=powershell-7). Basically a module that will work in Windows Powershell and Powershell Core. I'm not too worried about api limitations between the two as most of my cmdlets will be simple. The examples on that page use .NET Standard to create the portable modules, but I'd like to use Core.

By Windows Powershell, I mean the built in (not Powershell Core) version of Powershell.

The dotnet cli templates (that are installed using `dotnet new -i Microsoft.PowerShell.Standard.Module.Template`) use .NET Standard 2.x, not Core. I haven't found any templates for Core.

Is it currently just impossible to use Core to create a regular Windows Powershell module (or Portable Module)?

For reference, this is the code I'm using in the C# module. I'm working on just being able to import the module. This is in a `.NET Core Class Library` project, using the `System.Management.Automation` NuGet package from https://powershell.myget.org/F/powershell-core/api/v3/index.json. I'm doing my best to follow [this tutorial](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/) on making a cmdlet, but trying to adapt from .NET Standard to .NET Core.

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PowershellTest
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "NetworkAdapter")]
    public class GetNetworkAdapterCmdlet : Cmdlet
    {
    }
}
```

The project builds without any errors or warning, but my Windows Powershell throws an error when trying to import the compiled dll:

```
Import-Module "C:\Code\<solution name>\PowershellTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\PowershellTest.dll"

Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I get the same error when using the `Microsoft.Powershell.SDK` NuGet package from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json instead of the previous package.

Project settings:

[image: Project settings]

NuGet Packages:

[image: NuGet packages]

Comment: Windows powershell don't run on .net core. You mean powershell (powershell-core)?

Comment: @DougMaurer If Windows Powershell doesn't run on Powershell Core, can .net core create a portable module, one that will run on both?

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/writing-portable-modules?view=powershell-7#powershell-standard-library you need to target 'Powershell Standard', the page says "For example, PowerShell Standard 5.1 is compatible with both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 6.0 or newer."

Comment: target 'Powershell Standard' applies?

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, the correct nuget package was "PowerShellStandard.Library"